# INSERT values from one table to another using SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run this SQL Query:

```
INSERT INTO controldata (field,value) 
VALUES (customer_billing_product_type, 
  SELECT name from customer_billing_product_types)
```

to insert all rows in the `customer_billing_product_types` table into the `controldata` table with the field always being `customer_billing_product_type` but i get an SQL Error saying:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'SELECT name from customer_billing_product_types)' at line 1
```

Comment: Writing each SQL instruction (e.g. `INSERT INTO`, `SELECT`, etc.) below one another helps greatly in solving syntax errors like these.

Answer (score 4):

The INSERT as you wrote it expects to insert one record, but then in `values` an entire set of records is returned. Try to change your query to

```
INSERT INTO controldata(field, value)
SELECT customer_billing_product_type, t.name FROM customer_billing_product_types t;
```

This selects all `t.name` values from `customer_billing_product_types`, adds `customer_billing_product_type` as column and inserts all the results into `controldata`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong syntax try below:

```
INSERT into controldata (field1) SELECT name from customer_billing_product_types;
```

If you want to keep a field as constant then you can use as per below:

```
INSERT into controldata (field,value) SELECT 'customer_billing_product_types',name from customer_billing_product_types;
```

Comment: You forgot the constant field.